iOS Deep Linking Issue: App Redirects to Home Screen but Doesn't Open and Display Content
I'm encountering an issue with deep linking on iOS where, upon clicking the links, the app redirects to the App Store or, if the app is already installed, it redirects to the home screen without opening the app or displaying the intended content.
Consequently, the app remains on the home screen, failing to open and show the expected content from the parameters in the URL. This problem obstructs our ability to track referral users effectively.
As branch.io does, we also want to make that type of feature.
How can I resolve this issue and ensure that the app opens and displays the content as intended when users click on deep links?
Thanks in advance!

You should research set up Universal link

Show the code you have implemented to process the incoming link and route to the appropriate place in your app

The app fails to open the expected app and its page issue, is usually caused when there is improper branch SDK integration in your iOS app. This happens when you fail to add bundle identifiers,info.plist, and domain details in the appropriate place in your app. So, Kindly double-check the basic implementation once. I'm sharing you the Basic integration docs for reference below.
https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-basic-integration#1-configure-branch-dashboard
https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-basic-integration#2-configure-bundle-identifier
https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-basic-integration#3-configure-associated-domains
https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-basic-integration#4-configure-infoplist

Is there any way, alternative to branch.io ?
